# How to get individual xml subnodes when using $xpathvar->query?

Tags: php, xml

I try to get the value of name, PreviewUrl, Description, etc when the country name (e.g.  `<Country name="US">` ) matches the country of the user from XML results like the one below:

```
<Offers>
   <Offer Id="656">
     <Name>The Hobbit Android</Name>
     <Platform>Android Smartphone & Tablet</Platform>
     <DailyCap>63</DailyCap>
     <PreviewUrl>https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kabam.fortress</PreviewUrl>
     <TrackingUrl>http://ads.ad4game.com/www/delivery/dck.php?offerid=656&zoneid=7711</TrackingUrl>
     <Description>The battle for Middle-earth has just begun! PLAY FOR FREE and join thousands worldwide to drive ..</Description>
     <RestrictedTraffic> Social traffic (facebook, etc), Social traffic (facebook, etc) Email MarketingM, Brand Bidding</RestrictedTraffic>
     <Countries>
       <Country name="US">
         <OptIn>SOI</OptIn><Rate>$3.75</Rate>
         <EndDate>2013-09-15 16:47:12</EndDate>
       </Country>
     </Countries>
   </Offer>
 </Offers>
```

When I try the php code below I get all the Nodes concatenated as one single string. How can I get the name, PreviewUrl, Description, etc. as individual strings when the country name matches?

```
$xmldoc = new DOMDocument();
        $xmldoc->load('http://traffic.ad4game.com/www/admin/offers-api.php');

        $xpathvar = new Domxpath($xmldoc);



        $queryResult = $xpathvar->query('//Country[@name="US"]/../..');

        foreach($queryResult as $result){
                echo $result->nodeValue;
        }
```

Edit: As for expected output, I expect that after obtaining the individual strings, I expect it to be something like:

```
<div id="offer656">
<a href="http://ads.ad4game.com/www/delivery/dck.php?offerid=656&zoneid=7711">
The Hobbit Android</a><br />The battle for Middle-earth has just begun! PLAY FOR FREE and join thousands worldwide to drive .. 
</div>
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the exact output you hope to get. It makes a difference if you just want to print all the node values to the screen, vs be able to organize them in a data structure such as an array for access later.  Either way though, the solution will involve something with `$result->childNodes()`

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to iterate through all child elements of xpath query, so add `/*` at end.

Second, pass the `nodeValue` results into an array where you can subscript for individual strings (i.e., `$value[0]`, `$value[1]`, ...) or run a `foreach` loop on array:

```
$xmldoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmldoc->load('http://traffic.ad4game.com/www/admin/offers-api.php');

$xpathvar = new Domxpath($xmldoc);

// ITERATE THROUGH ALL CHILD ELEMENTS 
$queryResult = $xpathvar->query('//Country[@name="US"]/../../*');

$value = [];
foreach($queryResult as $result){
        // PRINTS ALL NODE VALUES OF XPATH AT ONCE
        echo $result->nodeValue;

        // PASSES EACH NODE VALUE OF XPATH INTO $VALUE ARRAY
        $value[] = $result->nodeValue;            
}

// OUTPUT $VALUE ARRAY CONTENTS
var_dump($value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `DOMXpath::evaluate()` not `DOMXPath::query()`. The two methods might look the same, but `evaluate()` supports Xpath expressions that return scalars. The second argument of the methods is a context. So you can iterate the `offer` nodes and use additional Xpath expressions to fetch the details:

```
$xmldoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmldoc->load('http://traffic.ad4game.com/www/admin/offers-api.php');

$xpath = new Domxpath($xmldoc);
$offers = $xpath->evaluate('//Offer[Countries/Country[@name="US"]]');

foreach($offers as $offer){
  var_dump(
    [
      'name' => $xpath->evaluate('string(Name)', $offer),
      'previewUrl' => $xpath->evaluate('string(PreviewUrl)', $offer)
    ]
  );
}
```